# Is this double pointer as head_reference?

Tags: c++

What is the use of node** head_ref ?This is a part of the code used to add an element inside a linked list. The original code had Node everywhere and I tried it with node as you all can see but it is not able to add any element in the list and the list is empty. Kindly tell the reason as why is it so.

```
void push(node** head_ref, int new_data){
node* new_node=new node;
new_node->data=new_data;
new_node->next=(*head_ref);
(*head_ref)=new node;
}
```

Comment: What do you think it is, and why aren't you sure?

Comment: Off topic but `(*head_ref)=new node;` should be `(*head_ref)=new_node;`

Comment: It took me a couple of seconds to see what @0x499602D2 was getting at, which suggests that `new_node` as a name could be improved on.

Answer (score 1):

A double pointer is just a pointer to a pointer. So `node** head_ref` is a pointer to a pointer, and `*head_ref` is a pointer.

Given the code, this looks like the head of an array of structures. In this case, `node** head_ref` points to the head of the first structure in the array, and so the pointer of that would be the structure itself.

In the function, the new node becomes the new head of the array, and the pointer to the `*head_ref` structure becomes the "next" element of the new node, essentially performing a push operation.

You can think of it as adding a link to the start of a chain, the chain remains as is, but the new link becomes the new head. Essentially, all chains are an empty chain to which heads are sequentially added onto one another.

In effect, everything is "the head of a chain" + "the rest of the chain" which is its own chain.

Learning a Lisp language should help you internalize this concept. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest element in the stack you want to push data on. But this code has an error where it just overwrites `head_ref` at the end. Please paste your full code.